# How can I yank two matches of regex group into two different registers?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, substitute, register

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23715908/3552975) teaches me how to yank matches of regex group into one register. But I want to yank two into two different registers. I've tried the following but failed.

```
:%s/\(regex1\)\(regex2\)/\=setreg('a', submatch(1))\=setreg('b', submatch(2))/n
```

An error thrown out says `invalid expression`. Then I modified it to be like this:

```
:%s/\(regex1\)\(regex2\)/\=setreg('a', submatch(1)) | \=setreg('b', submatch(2))/n
```

Then I get the error `E493 backwards range given`.

Can I do what I want? If so, how should I correct this snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to give back a single (replace) result; so, concatenate works:

```
:%s/\(regex1\)\(regex2\)/\=setreg('a', submatch(1)) . setreg('b', submatch(2))/n
```

Comment: Yeh, it works. Thanks. Can you tell me how to get the help manual for me to further learn it myself?

Comment: You're welcome - I went from reading `:help :substitute` to `:help sub-replace-special`, and from there, to `:help sub-replace-expression`, as this is were the reading of those help sections pointed me to (by following `\=`). And in the 3rd mentioned section, there is an example that concatenates 3 strings in the replace part. This gave me the idea.